# console.log not coming in Visual Studion 2013 Update 5

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, silverlight, visual-studio-2013, ibm-mobilefirst

I have created the **WindowsPhone8** project using `IBM MobilFirst Studio Version 7`. This is creating **Window Phone Silverlight 8.1** project for VS (Visual Studio).

When I put `console.log` in js file and test the application on device, that logs are not coming in Visual Studio's Output console.

In output console, I have also filter the messages by **Javascript**. In debug section of project properties, it is not showing me **Native with Script** option.

Is there any option I have to enable or some configuration I have to do in order to enable `console.log` in VS?

**Edit 1:** I have tried WL.Logger.warn, WL.Logger.error and WL.Logger.info, but none of them works.

Comment: Did you try WL.Logger...?

Comment: I have just tried WL.Logger.warn, but it is also not working on Emulator.

Comment: @IdanAdar, I have also downloaded one of the sample for MF7 and tried to put the log, but logs are not coming in VS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a limitation of Silverlight-Visual Studio itself and not MFP. To debug a MFPF Silverlight application, you can follow the approaches mentioned in this [article](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/08/14/debugging-a-mfp-sliverlight-and-windows-8-1-universal-apps/).

Answer (score 0):

What I have done is, I made **Logger.cs (C#)** file and place the following code to work it as plugin.

```
namespace Cordova.Extension.Commands
{
    class Logger : BaseCommand
    {
        public void log(String options) {
            //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Logging From Plugin");
            string optVal = null;
            try {
                optVal = JsonHelper.Deserialize<string[]>(options)[0];
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(optVal);
                DispatchCommandResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, "Logger Logged"));
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                DispatchCommandResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.ERROR, "Logger signaled an error"));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my js file, I have overrided console.log, WL.Logger.warn, WL.Logger.info and other loggers as follows.

```
    console.log = function (message) {
        cordova.exec("", "", "Logger", "log", ["Log : " + message]);
    }
    WL.Logger.warn = function ( message ) {
        cordova.exec("", "", "Logger", "log", ["Warning : " + message]);
    }
    WL.Logger.error = function (message) {
        cordova.exec("", "", "Logger", "log", ["Error : " + message]);
    }
    WL.Logger.debug = function (message) {
        cordova.exec("", "", "Logger", "log", ["Debug : " + message]);
    }
    WL.Logger.info = function (message) {
        cordova.exec("", "", "Logger", "log", ["Info : " + message]);
    }
```

In **config.xml** file, I have registered my plugin and now each and every Log is shown in VS Output Console, no requirement of **Vorlon.js**

```
<feature name="Logger">
      <param name="wp-package" value="Logger" />
  </feature>
```